# Updating Service reference WCF in VS2010 SP1 (mvc3 project) TFS -- Causes other developer failing to compile

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, tfs

On my local machine, I consume a WCF service via the Service References.  I can add to the other WCF project and check in to TFS , run the service,  Go to my main project and Click on Update Service Reference, and my web.config is fine whether change is needed or not.  Rebuild is fine.

However, on another developer's machine, they make a change to the WCF Service run it, and go to main project and Update Service Reference, and sometimes the web.config get trampled, it doesn't show the Url to the wcf service etc...   Thus compiling project causes a issue where it cannot find the namespace for the service reference.

Then if I get latest and checkin and tell a developer to get latest, their web.config will update, but they still increasingly have a problem with the namespace for the service reference does not exist.  It is running, the update to the service works.  The Url in the browser shows the endpoints.... but vs 2010 sp1 has repository files that cannot find the service reference for some reason. "Are you missing an assembly reference?"    Any ideas??

Comment: This may not be a TFS issue, perhaps it a a WCF / Service Reference issue.  Anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you please provide a list of your project names with their project types and the namespaces used during service generation (the project default namespaces). And the exact error namespace and assembly your VS is complaining about. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with TFS, just some kind of namespace confict during service reference update.

Comment: I started a new contract elsewhere 3 weeks ago.   Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in the svcutil dialog, the option to use shared assemblies is turned on, and if any signed assemblies are not an exact match, the checked in version will fail on the other machine.

You need to make sure the assemblies used have the same public key token.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I missed this answer and I see what you are saying